# How to customize the tab-widget in Fragment Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I am using Fragment Activity to customize the tab-widget, before I enter into Fragment Activity I use TabActivity, now it is deprecated. So I am going to update it to Fragment Activity, but I don't know how to customize the tab bar and adding the content of each tab. Can any one know help me to solve the issue.

**Java Coding**

```
private void setTabs()
{
    addTab("tab1", R.drawable.tab1, tab1.class);
    addTab("tab2", R.drawable.tab2, tab2.class);

    addTab("tab3", R.drawable.tab3, tab3.class);
    addTab("tab4", R.drawable.tab4, tab4.class);
}

private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c)
{
    FragmentTabHost tabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId); 

    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, null, false);
    TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(labelId);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

    spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited ...
use this line to inflate the fragment tab :)

```
mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.tab_layout, null);
```

Cheer up

It's Easy my friend: The answer lies in your Tabhot. see you part of code.

```
tabHost.addTab(newTab(Constants.TAG_MainActivity, R.string.hello_world, R.id.tab1));
tabHost.addTab(newTab(Constants.TAG_Search, R.string.hello_world, R.id.tab2));
tabHost.addTab(newTab(Constants.TAG_Maps_Location, R.string.hello_world, R.id.tab3));
tabHost.addTab(newTab(Constants.TAG_More_Page, R.string.hello_world, R.id.tab4));

tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.footer_home_selector);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.footer_search_selector);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.footer_camera_selector);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.footer_more_selector);

private TabSpec newTab(String tag, int labelId, int tabContentId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "buildTab(): tag=" + tag);

    TabSpec tabSpec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag);
    tabSpec.setIndicator("");
    tabSpec.setContent(tabContentId);
    return tabSpec;
}
```

Comment: i want to add inflate the Customized views.

Answer (score 0):

To add tab, you have to use tabhost object.
After setting up your tabhost try adding new tab as :

```
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab1",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab1)),Tab1.class, null);
```

This will create tab along with tab title and icon.
If you wish to set background for tab then use :

```
View v = mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);
v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_bg);
```

Here , **i** is position of your tab.

Comment: I've used the same thing in my app. If you still face any issue then you may ask.